# Angular 6 nested array use in ngfor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular6, ngfor

I have below nested array
[image]

I this picture I have array of key and data

Now second picture shows the structure of data

[image]

I am trying to bind this using ngfor nested

```
*ngFor="let item of groupByOrgData"
*ngFor="let cof of item.data
 {{cof.element.checklistAssociatedTo}}
```

Below is the code I am using to generate the array

```
 this.groupByOwn = [];
      res.forEach(item => {
        this.groupByOwn.push({ id: item.id, element: item, groupBy: item.orgId + '_' + item.orgName });

      });
      this.groupByOrg = _.groupBy(this.groupByOwn, function (n) {
        return n.groupBy
      });
      let props = Object.keys(this.groupByOrg);
      this.groupByOrgData = [];
      for (var prop of props) {
        this.groupByOrgData.push({ key: prop, data: this.groupByOrg[prop] });
      }
```

But its not working

Please help

Comment: try `cof.element.checklistAssociatedTo`

Comment: sorry mymistake,I am doing the same, wrongly typed, stll its not working

Comment: It should work. Can you provide you component code.

Comment: component code. you mean to say component.ts code

Comment: I have use _ group by method to group the items

Comment: I have updated my .ts code

Comment: plz change `*ngFor="let item of groupByOrgData"
*ngFor="let cof item.data
 {{cof.element.checklistAssociatedTo}}` to `*ngFor="let item of groupByOrgData"
*ngFor="let cof  of item.data"
 {{cof.element.checklistAssociatedTo}}`

Comment: you mean to say adding of , sorry again that is typo mistake, I have of there

Comment: It looks like my array is different with other normal nested array, as when I run nested for loop in .ts code it is not showing proper value

Comment: You code seem fine. Plz do one experiment in single `*ngFor` and try printing `{{item.key}}`.

Comment: yes, that is working, the upper loop is fine, I am not able to iterate with inner data array

Comment: Even when I iterate *ngFor="let cof of item.data" and printing simple text its not showing, means item.data is not iterating

Comment: My array is slightly different you can see it has lable data then array

Comment: I didn't understand, your array is different means ?
It's a java script array right.

Comment: Plz try create this function in component `getStringData(data: any){ return JSON.stringify(data); }` and in template `<div *ngFor="let item of groupByOrgData"> {{ getStringData(item.data) }} </div>`. plz provide output in comment.

Comment: the same thing I have started trying after not finding anything

Comment: what JSON string you got in browser ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/E2A9suOjImqgeFIpnXWR?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180496/discussion-between-md-parvez-alam-and-aagam-jain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in my local.

And after some changes it is working.

hello-world.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of org">
    <p>{{item.key}}</p>

    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let it of item.data">{{it.element.ca }}</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

hello-world.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hello-world',
  templateUrl: './hello-world.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hello-world.component.css']
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {
  org: any  = [
    {
       "key":"Human Resources_Human Resources",
       "data":[
          {
             "id":"1HwahYXr5hs3IDTn7RtC",
             "element":{
                "id":"1HwahYXr5hs3IDTn7RtC",
                "ca":"1x"

             },
             "groupBy":"Human Resources_Human Resources"
          },
          {
             "id":"I7kCoWl7JLCWvgSdZm6p",
             "element":{
                "id":"I7kCoWl7JLCWvgSdZm6p",
                "ca":"2x"

             },
             "groupBy":"Human Resources_Human Resources"
          },
          {
             "id":"TkXA0CyTlfDbTsirg45p",
             "element":{
                "id":"TkXA0CyTlfDbTsirg45p",
                "checklistAscasociatedTo":"3x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Human Resources_Human Resources"
          },
          {
             "id":"hW0DYe2zOBO6AzP3MxbC",
             "element":{
                "id":"hW0DYe2zOBO6AzP3MxbC",
                "ca":"4x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Human Resources_Human Resources"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "key":"Marketing_Marketing",
       "data":[
          {
             "id":"Ltgk4vvKNILwYry1thXL",
             "element":{
                "id":"Ltgk4vvKNILwYry1thXL",
                "ca":"5x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Marketing_Marketing"
          },
          {
             "id":"aA43supw5IYmVLkniC8c",
             "element":{
                "id":"aA43supw5IYmVLkniC8c",
                "ca":"6x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Marketing_Marketing"
          },
          {
             "id":"jIIbXuaaQP4aRKK2c6GD",
             "element":{
                "id":"jIIbXuaaQP4aRKK2c6GD",
                "ca":"7x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Marketing_Marketing"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "key":"Sales_Sales",
       "data":[
          {
             "id":"WwYl7FelUSVo8i5eMYMk",
             "element":{
                "id":"WwYl7FelUSVo8i5eMYMk",
                "ca":"8x"
             },
             "groupBy":"Sales_Sales"
          }
       ]
    }
 ];
}
```

[image]

You can also download full Angular project from here.

http://calm-haircut.surge.sh/SO_52436935.zip

You will need to run `npm install` because I removed "node_modules" from the project.

Comment: Could you please let me know what specifically you changed,other than ol I am not able to see

Comment: you were using `{{org.key}}` and `*ngFor="let it of org.data"`. I changed `org` to `item`.

Comment: in plnkr I left, because you were replicating on local, but in code I am doing same, as I said in post

Comment: I changed nothing else.

Comment: You know I am super duper dumb person, my code was working from starting, I was modifying someone else code and he had used collapsible panel so inner list was collapsed and no sign for collapsible panel, I wasted 4 hrs.:(

Comment: ha ha. Good Day :)